# Jhipster login with email instead of username

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, jhipster

I create app using Jhipster. By default it use combination of username+password to login. I would like to create email+password login so i can make username not unique. What is the best way to do this ?

I am using JWT.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739550/jhipster-authentication-login-with-email

Comment: Edited my post. Its not duplicated since i am using JWT not Oauth2

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3426#issuecomment-211994008

Answer (score 3):

By default the login field is used to log the user into the application. But with the last JHipster version (I'm not sure since which version it was implemented to) you can log user by email.

In the DomainUserDetailsService.java :

```
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
    log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);

    if (new EmailValidator().isValid(login, null)) {
        return userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByEmail(login)
            .map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(login, user))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User with email " + login + " was not found in the database"));
    }

    String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(lowercaseLogin)
        .map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(lowercaseLogin, user))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the database"));

}
```

But the login is still unique, as the mail is, firstname and lastname are not. Even if you have an old version of JHipster i'm pretty sure you can add this code to support both email and login authentication.

tested with JWT and last JHipster version !

Comment: Issue is that i need login not to be unique and if i remove signin with username, social networks are not working

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you want to do this but nevermind. If you want to login not be unique you should remove the sql constraint and update the JPA annotation in user.java entity.

If the application is already running on an environnment be sure to do a new changelog instead of modify the original one.

Comment: Well i want to allow people to have same username.