# how can I remove a field from jhipster's JHI_USER table?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

What is the best practice for removing a field/column from jhipster's user table ? I want to remove the login column.

Comment: Are you aware of the implications if you remove the `login` column? the whole user management system would probably fail.

Comment: @vicpermir Im trying to figure out how to login via email. Do i have to keep the login column to be able to do that ?

Comment: You can do authentication via email without removing the `login` column. Here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918317/jhipster-login-with-email-instead-of-username